# How to refresh a grid and chart

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

Refresh the grid and chart when clicking the refresh button in kendo ui

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of these should be what you are looking for:

```
$('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read();
$('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.refresh();

$('#ChartName').data().kendoChart.dataSource.read();
$('#ChartName').data().kendoChart.refresh();
```

Comment: :) No wonder I couldn't find it!!
$('#ChartName').data().kendoChart.refresh(); 
Was magic, thank you!